# Boost Thread defer thread creation

Tags: c++, boost-thread

I would like to create thread object as a member variable such as

```
boost::thread t;
```

I would then like to assign it a method and launch it.

Currently I do this:

```
 boost::thread t(Myfunction);
```

The above lauches the thread immediately.I would like to defer the thread creation.

I came across this [post](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/16) but I am not sure if anything has been done to accommodate that request ?